# Flask-SQLAlchemy - Transfer / Import Data From SQLite to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am relatively new in database system design. I need to build a tool using Flask-SQLAlchemy which accepts relatively smaller SQLite databases (intermediate DBs) as its input and stores the data into a MySQL database (central DB / master record).

My questions are:

1. What is the most efficient (and possibly performant) programmatic way to achieve this goal? What libraries / extensions do I need to use?
2. I did some research and found some suggestions to convert the intermediate DBs to other format first, e.g. CSV, XML, before inserting the data to the central DB. Do I need to perform this conversion?

Few notes:

- I have the schema for the central DB already defined using Flask-SQLAlchemy ORM.
- The schemas of intermediate DB and central DB are not one-to-one. However, the columns in intermediate DB can be seen as the subset of the columns in the central DB.